# In VScode - how to debug the child of a second fork command in an executable (cpp20)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, fork, parent-child, vscode-debugger

I am using vscode.
I am using the flag "followForkMode": "child" in my launch.json under "configuration" attribute:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "myExe",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "path_to/my.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "some_path",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [{
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }],
            "followForkMode": "child"
        },
```

In my main(), I have 2 forks and I only need to debug the child of the second fork.
Since I use 'followForkMode: child' - I am getting the child of the first fork and the code does not reach to the second fork.

Any ideas?

I tried conditional break-points, but it'ss no use since the "followForkMode : child" is present in the launch.json, I will never get the parent after the 1st fork - the only way to reach to the second fork in my code. I cannot switch the forks.

I also tried to use "processId": "${command:pickProcess}", but vscode prompts me to choose a pid at the begining of the run of the executable, and the second fork inside it hasn't been reached yet.

Comment: As for now, the only easy and non-technical solution is to place a breakpoint on the fork command , and use the  debugger's "continue" until the relevant execution arrives, and then open a gdb terminal and execute a vscode command with the gdb flag "set follow-fork-mode child", and then the next "continue" will be of the child. No solution was found until now to only place a break point in the code of the child.